# Error encountered in deploying ruby on rails web app to digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, dockerfile, port, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to digital ocean and is using a docker file for the build and deployment.

The building phase has no issue, but the deployment phase is where I'm encountering persistent error after trying to troubleshoot it.

This is the error that shows in the Deploy Log

```
[2023-12-08 07:54:56] /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/arguments.rb:137:in `parse_numeric': Expected numeric value for '--port'; got "$PORT" (Thor::MalformattedArgumentError)
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb:252:in `parse_peek'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/parser/options.rb:115:in `parse'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:79:in `initialize'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:26:in `initialize'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:45:in `initialize'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:124:in `initialize'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:388:in `new'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:388:in `dispatch'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-7.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from /usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
[2023-12-08 07:54:56]   from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

And these are the contents of my docker file

```
# Generated by Cloud66 Starter
FROM ruby:3.1.2

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs yarn 

ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# This installs bundler 2x. Change if you need any of the older versions
RUN gem install bundler:2.1.2
ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
# This is a bundler 2 format. For bundler 1, you can add --without development test to the bundle install line
RUN bundle config set without 'development test'
RUN bundle install

# Install Python 3.10 and pip
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt $APP_HOME/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ADD . $APP_HOME
# if you're not using webpack, you can comment out the following line
RUN yarn install --check-files
ENV SECRET_KEY_BASE=<redacted>
RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=$SECRET_KEY_BASE RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

CMD ["./bin/rails", "server", "-p", "3000", "-e", "production"]
```

I'm not sure if I'm troubleshooting it correctly, but I've tried modifying the port to 8080 which is the http port set in the app settings in digital ocean. As well as the other way around which is to keep the port value in my docker file to 3000 but change the http port settings of the app, in digital ocean.

Comment: Your Dockerfile looks fine. The problem is that the port is set to "$PORT" as a string somewhere. I'm not familiar with Digital Ocean, but according to their docs, they allow overwriting the default command: 4. Configure resources for your app at https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/deploy-from-container-images/ Could you check it?